# /dev/i2c-0 file not found

Tags: c, linux, driver

I have successfully compiled linux kernel3.5.4 by enabling i2c on my PC. 
I want to use i2cdevinterface from user space. So i created small c program in user space.
Then i created `mknod /dev/i2c-0 c 89 0`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
main()
{

  int fd;
  char *name="/dev/i2c-0";
  fd=open(name,O_RDWR);

}
```

**output:**
 **/dev/i2c-0 file not found**

In /proc/modules i don't find i2c-dev module.
In modules.builtin file in can see kernel/derives/i2c/i2c-dev.ko

My question is why i am getting /dev/i2c-0 file not found and no module in /proc/modules.

Comment: Did you compile the I2C support as a module? If so, have you either used `modprobe` or `insmod` to get the module loaded?

Comment: In .config file for i2c it is y.